# Reference to 'this' in a prototype is not working

Tags: javascript

```
var MyClass = function() { 
    //some functionality goes here 
};

MyClass.prototype.xyz = function() { 
    //some functionality goes here 
};

MyClass.prototype.abc = function() {
    var self = this;
    // here self is not working and 'this.xyz()' isn't working too.
    self.xyz();
    // It works if I use MyClass.prototype.xyz();
};
```

Can someone help with what I am missing here?

Comment: Add **Complete** code.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484/218196)

Comment: The value of `this` depends **not** on how you define your function but on how you call your function. Since you don't show how you call the function `abc` we cannot help you

Comment: The value of `this` depends on how you call a function. You haven't shown us how you call the function. You should provide a real [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

I don't really know how you call your functions here, but this works perfectly:

```
var MyClass = function() { 
    console.log("constructor");
};

MyClass.prototype.xyz = function() { 
    console.log("xyz");
};

MyClass.prototype.abc = function() {
    console.log("abc");
    this.xyz();
};

let myClass = new MyClass();

myClass.xyz();
myClass.abc();
```

and the output is simple:

```
constructor
xyz
abc
xyz
```